# Handle multiple users update a same form in web application

Tags: java, javascript, html

Suppose user A has open a form with populated data.

While user A do modifications to the form data, user B opens the same form with data populated for user A.

Then while user B doing the modification to the data, user A has click on submit the form which updated the record.

So now when user B finish update the form and click on submit button, a warning message should display that this record been already modified while he is doing modification to the data so he can reload the form again.

I guess this is the best solution(warning message) in user perspective for this kind of situation right? So how to achieve this in back end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to maintain a `version` of document(form data) in your `database`.So while fetching the information from database,you can read the version value,and on submit just validate and increment it.

So in your case below will happen.

> 1.User A read form data (version 1)
>
> 2.User B read from data (version 1)
>
> 3.User A submit the data(now match the version with value in DB,it is still 1, so just increment 1,now it's value is 2 in DB).
>
> 4.Now when User B submit the form,while matching the value,will find mismatch (1(step2) != 2(current value in DB)).
>
> 5.From this point,you can raise some error message/warning to front end.

It's kind of optimistic locking.

See :- [Optimistic Concurrency Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JPA/Hibernate, you can see if the dirty check flag is true

Answer (score 0):

It might be the best solution for you, but definitely not the only one.

There's a possibility to actually update the data in the form in real time while a user enters it (not having to click on submit). That way the other users seeing the same document can see what everyone else is doing, sort of like Google Docs.

With websockets, it's not even that hard to implement. [Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/start-using-html5-websockets-today--net-13270)'s a tutorial mostly for client-side scripting and a few links to some back-end modules. If none of those work for your back-end needs I'm sure there'll be a module and some example code in your language of preference if you search google for it.